# Jenkins could not resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a problem with jenkins version 1.500. i am trying to build a project with a dependency to another project of mine. 
The error is:

> `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project projectname: Could not resolve dependencies for project projectname:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find reference-project:jar:1.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

If I build this project via console and Maven, the whole projects build succeed. 
I checked the dependency jar file in the repository, it is there at the right place.

Does Maven have a own repository or did I miss something?

But under the Jenkins system settings, I chose "Default(~/.m2/repository)" and I did not check the checkbox "use own repository" at the project settings. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I created a extra job for the dependency in jenkins and called the Maven goal install and then everything works fine. Before this step I installed the dependency via Console and mvn install. 
Why is there a difference? (i tried the given solution with delete and reinstall, but this did not help)

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution delete the folder from the *~/.m2/repository* which represents the artifact you've written about. *~/.m2/repository/${groupId}/...* and rebuild. That happens sometimes if you have some problems during download of the artifact etc.

Answer (score 0):

I too have similar problem and tried deleting the folder in ~/.m2/repository/
still its now downloading dependencies from remote repository location to local